# Create template object based on another template object

Tags: c++, templates

I have a generic point and rectangle class as follows:

```
template < typename T > struct Pt
  { T x; T y; };

template < typename T > struct Rect
  { T x; T y; T w; T h; };
```

I have a function that accepts two `Rect`s and tests to see if they overlap. I want to implement this by calling my "Pt within Rect" function four times. But i want to know how i would create a point without knowing the type of data stored in the rect. I was hoping for something like this:

```
bool RectsOverlap ( Rect a, Rect b )
  {
  Pt /*do i put sonethig here?*/ p = Pt(a.x, a.y);
  ...
  p = Pt(a.x + a.w, a.y);
  ...
  }
```

Or something to that effect.

Comment: Btw, it's easier to check that they are not overlapping and negate the result.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can make your function a template:

```
template <typename T>
bool RectsOverlap (const Rect<T>& a, const Rect<T>& b )
{
  Pt<T> p(a.x, a.y);
  ...
  p = Pt<T>(a.x + a.w, a.y);
  ...
 }
```

Note that the `Rects` are passed by const reference, since it doesn't seem like you need to copy them or modify them.

Answer (score 0):

```
template <typename T>
bool rectsOverlap(const Rect<T>& a, const Rect<T>& b)
{
    Pt<T> p( ... , ... );
    ...
    return ...;
}
```